# Exporting List Settings/Schema for documentation purposes

Tags: list, sharepoint, export, schema

Is anyone aware of how, either OOTB or via a plugin, to export a SharePoint list schema and settings into a readable format for documentation purposes?

I known you can template a list (and contents) but that does help in this instance.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
http://Server/SiteCollection/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=ExportList&List={GUID}
```

Rferece [this thread](https://vaqarhyder.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-exporting-schemaxml-file-of.html)

Or PowerShell [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-Lists-Schema-as-XML-c472d82c) if you're using SharePoint 2013 and above.

Comment: That does appear to pull everything, is there a recommended way to process/filter/present so it's more readable. Ideally I just want to list a basic table with the column names, column types, and where choice/calc etc what those choices or calcs are.